# ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version

Tags: mysql, mariadb

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'select 1 from user_info where user_id = p_user_id))THEN select 'Username Exits !' at line 3



CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_create_user`(IN p_user_id varchar(20),IN p_user_pw varchar(20))
BEGIN
IF (select exits (select 1 from user_info where user_id = p_user_id))THEN select 'Username Exits !!';
```

Comment: it should be `exists` not `exits`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First is to remove `select()` on your `IF` condition, second change `exits` to `exists`.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_create_user( IN p_email varchar(80), IN p_username varchar(45), IN p_password varchar(45)) 
BEGIN 
    IF (exists (select 1 from user where username = p_username)) 
    THEN select 'Username Exists !!';
    ELSE 
        insert into user (email, username, password) values (p_email, p_username, p_password); 
    END IF; 
END //
```

Try [DBFIDDLE](https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=FBmMeDeGMK)

Comment: CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_create_user`( IN p_email varchar(80),
IN p_username varchar(45), IN p_password varchar(45))
 
BEGIN
IF ( select exists (select 1 from user where username = p_username) ) THEN
    select 'Username Exists !!';
ELSE
insert into user (email, username, password) 
values (p_email, p_username, p_password);
 
END IF;
END $$   ###################ERROR#############

Comment: updated with complete stored procedure script, please try

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manurresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use neane 4 THEN select 'Username Exists !!';

Comment: you can try DBFIDDLE, check the link

Comment: Thanks you ~~ Thanks you ~~ Thanks you ~~ Thanks you ~~